# How does WeChat's app market work? Native apps? Web views?

Tags: mobile, uiwebview, android-webview, native, wechat

I don't live in China, so I can't play with this on my own, but I know that WeChat has something like an app market within the native WeChat apps.

Lets say I wanted to create a marketplace for 3rd party apps within my own app. Would the apps in my marketplace be native apps with Java for Android or Swift/Objtive C? Or are they "apps" that live in a web view. How does WeChat do this?

Do you know of other examples of app marketplaces within 3rd party apps?

Comment: So what you are saying is that they have different apps in one app?

Comment: @Steven yes, thats what I understand. (though I can't see it because those features are only open to users in China)

Comment: With other apps in WeChat do you mean this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WeChat#Features

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell. It doesn't look like there are multiple 3rd party apps inside WeChat after all. So this is not a valid question.

Comment: did you found answer? I have tried several apps, but they don't look like web views to me. Are they already part of the wechat, and just enabled, or is there something more to this?